# Allow user to enter username before mounting shared drive

Tags: command-line, terminal, mount, cifs

I have a mount drive which I usually mount using

`sudo cifs -o "username=myshareddrive_username,uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g)" //server-address/folder /mount/path/on/ubuntu`

Now, I have some linux machines which are accessible by some users. On each machine there is only one user account for all users to use to login to the machine. I wonder how I can allow the users to mount the shared drive using their shared-drive network credentials without having to open terminal and running a command as some of them are not very good in technical things? noting that each user has his unique network credentials (username and password) on the shared drive.

Comment: Is it the same `//server-address/folder` for all your users?

Comment: @roaima yes, but users will use different network credentials (username and password)

Comment: You're using CIFS. Is your file server on an AD domain? If so could you join the Linux machines to your AD domain and benefit from implicit user account trust?

Comment: @roaima Yes, my file server is on an AD domain, how I can add the machine to my domain so users can use their workplace username to login to the machines? I did this with the windows machine, but I don't know how it can be done with linux ones

Comment: It varies slightly depending on Linux distribution but essentially you need to install the `sssd` and `realmd` packages, then run `realm` to configure. You may need to adjust the configuration slightly to give users their existing UIDs rather than having `sssd` map them from user's SIDs.

Comment: @roaima I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 any advice with a link having the steps I can follow please?